# Pictures size and camera preview size issue

Tags: android, image, camera

I am working on camera app with camera preview. The preview is in a 2.5 weight frame layout of 4 weight sum:

```
<LinearLayout ...
//some xml

android:weightSum="4" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:background="#000000" >

</FrameLayout>
```

but when I take a picture, the pictures shows details more than the frame layout weight, like this:

**camera preview looks like:**

[image: camera preview looks like:]

**captured picture looks like:**

[image: captured picture looks like:]

the question is how can I make the captured image look like what appears in the preview?

Answer (score 0):

Your preview shows what you set it up to show, but the camera seems to take the image in its entirety. You should be able to scale/cut/etc the picture to match the preview, or maybe you want to set up the camera preview in other ways as explained in Android docs here:

[Controlling the Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

Kaamel